# How can I use a pytest fixture as a parametrize argument?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a pytest test like so:

```
email_two = generate_email_two()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('email', ['email_one@example.com', email_two])
def test_email_thing(self, email):
        ... # Run some test with the email parameter
```

Now, as part of refactoring, I have moved the line:

```
email_two = generate_email_two()
```

into its own fixture (in a conftest.py file), as it is used in various other places. However, is there some way, other than importing the fixture function directly, of referencing it in this test? I know that funcargs are normally the way of calling a fixture, but in this context, I am not inside a test function when I am wanting to call the fixture.

Comment: Sounds like a `session-fixture` could help: https://pytest.org/latest/example/special.html

Comment: @dm295 I could do something like that...but that would couple the fixture to the place where it is being called (I think). In the sense that the fixture would be attaching itself onto a specific class. Although, alternatively, the fixture could attach to _every_ class, or something like that, but that seems a bad solution.

Comment: You can't use fixtue in parametrization. https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349/using-fixtures-in-pytestmarkparametrize

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up doing this by having a for loop in the test function, looping over each of the emails. Not the best way, in terms of test output, but it does the job.

```
import pytest
import fireblog.login as login

pytestmark = pytest.mark.usefixtures("test_with_one_theme")

class Test_groupfinder:
    def test_success(self, persona_test_admin_login, pyramid_config):
        emails = ['id5489746@mockmyid.com', persona_test_admin_login['email']]
        for email in emails:
            res = login.groupfinder(email)
            assert res == ['g:admin']

    def test_failure(self, pyramid_config):
        fake_email = 'some_fake_address@example.com'
        res = login.groupfinder(fake_email)
        assert res == ['g:commenter']
```